# NicEdit form reset button w/o effect

Tags: forms, reset, nicedit

I have a form, with some NicEdit textboxes and some common inputs, various default values.

When I hit the reset button

```
<input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" class="btn">
```

all values get resetted to their defaults as expected, but not the NicEdit textareas.

Is there a special JS hook or something I need to set so that the NicEdit enhanced textarea's can get resetted?

There is no warning/error/.. output in the dev console.

Answer (score 0):

NicEdit built his own text area with a div.
On a form reset NicEdit don't get the reset of the textarea.
I think you have to use the onreset handler of the form to delete your NicEdit text area for yourself.

```
<form id="test" name="test" onReset="myreset();">
<input type="text" value="" />
<textarea id="area1" name="area1" cols="40"></textarea>
<input name="clear" type="reset" value="clear" />
</form>

function myreset(){
   var ne = nicEditors.findEditor("area1");
   ne.setContent("");
}
```

See the example http://jsfiddle.net/mtv8V/